# How to hide or remove an element onClick in React?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, components, hide

I am trying to hide an element 'GorillaSurfIn' after I click on it.
But also it should fire the 'setShouldGorillaSurfOut' to 'true'. The second part works, but after I added this function:

```
function hideGorillaSurfIn() {
    let element = document.getElementById('gorilla-surf-in');
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(element).style.display = 
  this.state.isClicked ? 'grid' : 'none';
}
```

After I click, the code falls apart.

Once I click, the element should be hidden/removed till the next time the App restarts.

Here is the [Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-antonelli-pgb8r) for further explanation.

I am open to any solutions, but also explanations please, as I am still fresh in learning React.

Comment: Just a few side notes: the way you manipulate visibility is completely inappropriate for react - instead of setting DOM elements style, you're expected to rely on state (either local or global) and modify that accordingly with event handlers; as long as you're using functional components allover the app, there's no `this.state` and for that same reason, you'd be much better off with [`useSelector()` and `useDispatch()` hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) rather then `connect`.

Comment: As for your specific problem, you should embed your attempted code into necessary component of your sandbox, otherwise it is not quite clear what exactly should be clicked and what is it expected to happen (and, furthermore, which exactly actions are needed to be dispatched).

Comment: Hi Yevgen, I do appreciate your input, however I am very new in all this and I find your explanation too advanced for me to understand. I am aware that you did not know that I am a new and I should probably know the terminology you are using, but most of it I do not comprehend. I do appreciate anyone who responds and uses their time to help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your code a bit to make it work. You can make further changes according to your need. A few things that I would like to add: -

1. You should avoid using findDOMNode (in most cases refs can solve your problem) as there are certain drawbacks associated with findDOMNode, such as the [react's documentation states](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html) "findDOMNode cannot be used with functional components".
   I've used refs (forward ref in this case) to make it work.
2. GorillaSurfIn was called twice, so there were two Gorilla gifs on the screen with same IDs. Not sure if that was the intended behaviour but each element should have unique ID.
3. Check out the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-pike-wgoiw?file=/src/containers/AddTodo.js).

Comment: Hey,
thanks for making it work. Do you recall (or know how) I can find out where else did you make changes in the project? Besides the AddTodo?

Comment: cause I changed the code in AddTodo and GorillaSurfOut, and the Gorilla still doesnt disapear, like it does in your code sandbox...

Comment: These are the line numbers in my codesandbox: -

AddTodo.js

1. Line no. 17 (created ref)
2. Line no. 31 (hideGorillaSurfIn function)
3. Line no. 43 (commented extra call to GorillaSurfIn)
4. Line no. 45 (passed callback and clickHandler)

Besides I also made a few changes in GorillaSurf.js and added CSS in myStyles.css

Comment: I didnt notice the CSS part. Now everything makes much more sense. Perfect! Thanks so much!